# How to change application installation path in chocolatey?

Tags: chocolatey

Just installed Chocolatey (open source edition). By default, it installs software to "С:\Program Files" folder. 
How can I change the default installation path (for example: "D:\Software")?

Answer (score 0):

The place where the software is installs varies from package to package. The free edition has no automatic way to control where the software get's installed, that usually gets set by the person that created the package or by the software itself.

That being said, if you don't have enough space on C, you can do something like use mklink /d to create a symlink to D:\Program Files and replace C:\Program Files with the link.